# EasyAdmin 4 URL generator redirect

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

How to redirect user to previous page after deleting Entity?

```
#[Route('/panel/remove/{id}', name: 'removethis')]
    public function RemoveThis(int $id)
    {
        $url = $this->adminUrlGenerator
            ->setController(SomethingCrudController::class)
            ->setAction('delete')
            ->setEntityId($id)
            ->generateUrl();
        return $this->redirect($url);
    }
```

Right now it redirects to homepage

Answer (score 2):

```
private $adminUrlGenerator;

public function __construct(AdminUrlGenerator $adminUrlGenerator)
{
    $this->adminUrlGenerator = $adminUrlGenerator;
}

#[Route('/admin/sync', name: 'admin_sync')]
public function sync()
{

    $url = $this->adminUrlGenerator
        ->setController(SyncCrudController::class)
        ->setAction(Action::INDEX)
        ->generateUrl();

    return $this->redirect($url);

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work as it should. Action which you've binded points to INDEX, while my code does delete. I need to redirect user after the DELETE is complete.

Comment: Use EventSubscriber (AfterEntityDeletedEvent). Then redirect.
https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/events.html